# Can not cast deserialized json array with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I was working with jackson lib in java to deserialize an json file to an array list.
First I use this method and everything worked fine.

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>) objectMapper.readValue(new File("data.json"), new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

Then I decided to refactor the code and write a generic method to use for any type of data.

```java
public static <T> ArrayList<T> listFromJson(String filename) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return (ArrayList<T>) objectMapper.readValue(new File(filename), new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});
}
```

This method returns the array list without any exceptions. But when I want to use an element of arraylist and store it in a variable the program throws exception like this.

```
User user = users.get(0);
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.example.User ...
    ....
```

I also tried to print out the element without casting and it wasn't an object reference. It was something like a hashmap.

I think it is related to generics but I don't know the cause.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object `User` is a `JsonNode`, something like this:

```
{
   "userName": "...",
   "email": "...",
   etc.
}
```

While this object can be mapped against a `User.class` if you specify so, when you don't say anything, the only guess that Jackson can take is that this is a `Map<String, Object>` (and the implementation a `LinkedHashMap`, meaning a map respecting its insertion order).

So when you refactored your method:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> listFromJson(String filename) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return (ArrayList<T>) objectMapper.readValue(new File(filename), new TypeReference<List<T>>() {});
}
```

... you said to Jackson that it will find a `List<T>` where `T` can be any object. The only guess it can take is it will be a JsonNode (hence a `Map.class`).

To solve this issue, you should pass the concrete `TypeReference` to the method as well:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> listFromJson(String filename, TypeReference<?> expectedTypeReference) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return (List<T>) objectMapper.readValue(new File(filename), expectedTypeReference);
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
TypeReference<List<User>> expectedTypeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
List<User> users = listFromJson(fileName, expectedTypeRef);
User user = users.get(0); // <-- this should work
```